# Syntax Error When I Try to Use Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm getting the following error when I try to use "grunt serve".

```
/Users/name/Documents/projectname/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:6755

});



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Documents/projectname/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/lib/findup-sync.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: You're missing some closing brackets/parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that produced the same `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` error for me. Resolution for this was to remove my project's node_modules directory and re-run npm install. If you are using a linux machine make sure to run it as `sudo npm install` whereas on windows you'll want to run your command prompt as Admin. Hope this helps!